# Convert part of dataframe to character list in R

Tags: r, list, character, dataframe

I am attempting to extract the header info from a large table and create a character list (so that I can use this list as a list of the variables contained in my table). I extract the header info in the following way (data is a date.frame):

```
vars = data[0,]
```

How do I now convert "vars" to a character list? When I do the following:

```
varsnew = as.character(vars)
```

I get the following result:

```
[1] "integer(0)" "integer(0)" "numeric(0)" "integer(0)" "integer(0)" "integer(0)"
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfect. I was unaware of this function.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the function called `colnames`. There is also a more general function called `names` that would also work in this case.